# Display Sonar Code Coverage with jacoco.exec file in Sonar LTS 7.9.2

Tags: ant, sonarqube, jacoco, jacoco-maven-plugin, sonarqube7

Recently I have updated SonarQube 7.9.2 in which `sonar.jacoco.reportPaths` property has been deprecated and need to use `sonar.coverage.jacoco.xmlReportPaths`. I don't have JaCoCo xml report generated and I am using ant for build and JUnit.

Please help me to view the coverage on SonarQube with `exec` file.

Comment: I've run into a similar problem with Maven and am pretty sure that old setting and `jacoco.exec` file does not work anymore. See my investigation of the problem at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61235045/sonarqube-maven-jacoco-gitlab-ci-sonar-started-to-show-0-code-coverage-a. So I had to replace it with JaCoCo xml report, and it worked.