# SonarQube + Maven + JaCoCo + GitLab CI: Sonar started to show 0% code coverage after upgrading to SonarQube 7.9.2

Tags: java, maven, sonarqube, code-coverage, jacoco

After we upgraded our SonarQube to `Version 7.9.2 (build 30863), Community Edition`, running the GitLab CI Pipeline results in showing `0.0%` coverage (dropping from about `86.2%`), although Sonar is showing all unit tests.

Maven build executed in `.gitlab-ci.yml` looks like this:

```
    - mvn test sonar:sonar -Dsonar.host.url=${SONAR_HOST_URL} -Dsonar.login=${SONAR_TOKEN}
```

Obviosuly this has something to deal with notorious `sonar.coverage.jacoco.xmlReportPaths` and `sonar.jacoco.reportPaths` Sonar-JaCoCo plugin settings (see https://docs.sonarqube.org/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=1442166).

After looking into the pipeline jobs logs, I found the following (project name obfuscated to `myProject`):

**Before SonarQube upgrade:**

```
[INFO] Sensor JaCoCo XML Report Importer [jacoco]
[INFO] Sensor JaCoCo XML Report Importer [jacoco] (done) | time=3ms
[INFO] Sensor SurefireSensor [java]
[INFO] parsing [/builds/myProject/target/surefire-reports]
[INFO] Sensor SurefireSensor [java] (done) | time=87ms
[INFO] Sensor JaCoCoSensor [java]
[WARNING] Property 'sonar.jacoco.reportPaths' is deprecated (JaCoCo binary format). 'sonar.coverage.jacoco.xmlReportPaths' should be used instead (JaCoCo XML format). Please check that the JaCoCo plugin is installed on your SonarQube Instance.
[INFO] Analysing /builds/myProject/target/jacoco.exec
[INFO] Sensor JaCoCoSensor [java] (done) | time=206ms
```

**After SonarQube upgrade:**

```
[INFO] Sensor JaCoCo XML Report Importer [jacoco]
[INFO] Sensor JaCoCo XML Report Importer [jacoco] (done) | time=3ms
[INFO] Sensor SurefireSensor [java]
[INFO] parsing [/builds/myProject/target/surefire-reports]
[INFO] Sensor SurefireSensor [java] (done) | time=86ms
[INFO] Sensor JavaXmlSensor [java]
[INFO] 1 source files to be analyzed
[INFO] Sensor JavaXmlSensor [java] (done) | time=302ms
```

Therefore the are obviously some differences in regards to `sonar.jacoco.reportPaths` setting.
Notably, I don't explicitly set any of the two settings.

How to fix parsing of the JaCoCo report so that it works (regardless with old or new setting)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Quick answer

Replace `mvn test` with `mvn verify`. No explicit settings declaration required.

### My investigation process

I've tried to execute the builds with the explicit setting values default settings.

**1)** Explicit default value of the deprecated setting: `-Dsonar.jacoco.reportPaths=target/jacoco.exec`.

This results in the following log, indicating that this setting won't work anymore for the new Sonar:

```
[INFO] Sensor JaCoCo XML Report Importer [jacoco] (done) | time=57ms
[INFO] Sensor SurefireSensor [java]
[INFO] parsing [/builds/myProject/target/surefire-reports]
[INFO] Sensor SurefireSensor [java] (done) | time=23ms
[INFO] Sensor Removed properties sensor [java]
[WARNING] Property 'sonar.jacoco.reportPaths' is no longer supported. Use JaCoCo's xml report and sonar-jacoco plugin.
[INFO] Sensor Removed properties sensor [java] (done) | time=1ms
```

Obviously, the coverage stays at `0.0%`.

See also a SO related Ant question on this topic: [Display Sonar Code Coverage with jacoco.exec file in Sonar LTS 7.9.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59527088/display-sonar-code-coverage-with-jacoco-exec-file-in-sonar-lts-7-9-2).

**2)** Explicit default value of the new setting: `-Dsonar.coverage.jacoco.xmlReportPaths=target/site/jacoco/jacoco.xml`

**Note:** although this default value is not (by some reason) documented on https://docs.sonarqube.org/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=1442166, I've just found it by searching for `jacoco.xml` in my local `target` directory.

Coverage stayed at `0.0%`, and the GitLab CI job log started to finally show something clear:

```
[INFO] Sensor SonarCSS Rules [cssfamily] (done) | time=1ms
[INFO] Sensor JaCoCo XML Report Importer [jacoco]
[WARNING] Report doesn't exist: '/builds/myProject/target/site/jacoco/jacoco.xml'
[INFO] Sensor JaCoCo XML Report Importer [jacoco] (done) | time=4ms
[INFO] Sensor SurefireSensor [java]
```

**!** It is a pity that this log is not written when running without the explicit settings. It will simplify the investigation a lot.

So now we have an understanding: `/target/site` is not generated on my GitLab CI pipeline. Obviously, this is because the script contains only `mvn test`, which does not get far enough through the [Maven Build Lifecycle](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html).

Looking into Maven + Sonar examples: they contain `mvn verify sonar:sonar` or `mvn install sonar:sonar`.

Therefore here we go:

**3)** `mvn verify` + explicit default value of the new setting: `-Dsonar.coverage.jacoco.xmlReportPaths=target/site/jacoco/jacoco.xml`

This worked! Coverage is shown on SonarQube and no errors present in the JaCoCo-related log part:

```
[INFO] Sensor JaCoCo XML Report Importer [jacoco]
[INFO] Sensor JaCoCo XML Report Importer [jacoco] (done) | time=94ms
[INFO] Sensor SurefireSensor [java]
[INFO] parsing [/builds/myProject/target/surefire-reports]
[INFO] Sensor SurefireSensor [java] (done) | time=92ms
[INFO] Sensor JavaXmlSensor [java]
[INFO] Sensor JavaXmlSensor [java] (done) | time=7ms
```

**4)** `mvn verify` without explicit setting.

So finally I tried without any settings values, and it works:

```
  - mvn verify sonar:sonar -Dsonar.host.url=${SONAR_HOST_URL} -Dsonar.login=${SONAR_TOKEN}
```

### Summary

- Old `sonar.jacoco.reportPaths` setting does not work on new SonarQube versions (7.9.2+).
- Default value of new `sonar.coverage.jacoco.xmlReportPaths` setting is `target/site/jacoco/jacoco.xml`.
- The root cause was that `/target/site/jacoco` directory was not generated (including `jacoco.xml` and all other files of the JaCoCo report)
- All I have to do is to replace `mvn test` with `mvn verify`.
- Main Sonar pitfall is not writing an error log about "report file not found" when the value of `sonar.coverage.jacoco.xmlReportPaths` is not explicitly set. It would be good for SonarQube developers to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Kindly use the following

```
mvn clean verify sonar:sonar -Dsonar.host.url=${SONAR_HOST_URL} -Dsonar.login=${SONAR_TOKEN}
```